# Trying to export a Haskell lib for C

Tags: c, haskell

I copied the example code in [the Haskell FFI guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ffi-ghc.html) as a first step to exporting my Haskell program as a C library, but can't get it to compile. I have `foo.hs`:

```
module Foo where
foreign export ccall foo :: Int -> IO Int

foo :: Int -> IO Int
foo n = return (length (f n))

f :: Int -> [Int]
f 0 = []
f n = n:(f (n-1))
```

This successfuly compiled to `foo_stub.h` and `foo_stub.o`. Here's `foo_stub.h`:

```
#include "HsFFI.h"
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
extern HsInt foo(HsInt a1);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

But then my C program didn't compile:

```
#include "foo_stub.h"
main() { foo(1); } // I realize this is probably wrong, and would also like advice on doing this part correctly, but note the error is not here.
```

error:

```
gcc foo.c
In file included from foo.c:1:0:
foo_stub.h:1:19: fatal error: HsFFI.h: No such file or directory
 #include "HsFFI.h"
                   ^
compilation terminated.
```

I assume I'm missing some header files or haven't pointed gcc to them correctly. I can provide more information if necessary. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found "HsFFI.h" at `/usr/local/lib/ghc-7.10.2/include/HsFFI.h`. You should be able to direct GCC to look there with the `-I` option. More information [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html).

Comment: Can't believe I didn't try this, I used `gcc foo.c -I "/usr/lib/ghc/include/"`

Comment: For future readers, use GHC to print out the libdir: `ghc --print-libdir`. I compiled a program like so: `gcc main.c -I "\`ghc --print-libdir\`/include"`