# GHC compile DLL for use in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, haskell, dll, ghc

This is an alternative approach to this question here: [Export Haskell lib as DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52662440/export-haskell-lib-as-dll)

I am working with GHC version 8.6.1 [latest] and am following [the documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/win32-dlls.html#building-and-using-win32-dlls) for compiling a DLL from a haskell library for the subsequent use in VBA.

My files look like this:

Adder.hs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Adder where

adder :: Int -> Int -> IO Int
adder x y = return (x+y)

foreign export ccall adder :: Int -> Int -> IO Int
```

StartEnd.c:

```
#include <Rts.h>

void HsStart() {
    int argc = 1;
    char* argv[] = {"ghcDll", NULL};
    char** args = argv;
    hs_init(&argc, &args);
}

void HsEnd() {
    hs_exit();
}
```

I copied the folder `ghc-8.6.1\lib\include` to the build location and copied the two files into that folder (because I cannot figure out how to pass the -I[PATH] parameter correctly).

Running these compilation steps, I get:

```
ghc -c Adder.hs
    --> no error
ghc -c StartEnd.c
    --> no error
ghc -shared -no-hs-main -o Adder.dll Adder.o Adder_stub.h StartEnd.o
    --> no error
```

and the files

```
Adder.dll
Adder.dll.a
Adder.hi
Adder.o
Adder_stub.h
startEnd.o
```

I tried using the third compilation command like it is in the documentation `ghc -shared -o Adder.dll Adder.o Adder_stub.h StartEnd.o` and with the parameter -no-hs-main just to be sure.

My VBA script looks like this:

```
Private Declare Function Adder Lib "PATH\TO\Adder.dll" Alias "adder" _
        (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long

Private Declare Sub HsStart Lib "PATH\TO\Adder.dll" ()
Private Declare Sub HsEnd Lib "PATH\TO\Adder.dll" ()

Public Sub test()
    HsStart
    MsgBox "12 + 5 = " & Adder(12, 5)
    HsEnd
End Sub
```

However, whenever I try to run the Sub test, I get the error message:

```
Run-Time error '48'
File not found:
PATH\TO\Adder.dll
```

Can you please tell me where I made a mistake and how I can fix it?

If it helps, the output of `dumpbin /EXPORTS Adder.dll` is this:

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.00.24234.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file Adder.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for Adder.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    5BBD9533 time date stamp Wed Oct 10 07:59:15 2018
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
       29737 number of functions
       29737 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 004E0F18 ALLOC_BH_adm
          ...
          75   4A 00001681 HsEnd
          76   4B 00001640 HsStart
          ...
          472  1D7 00001540 adder
          ...
```

My Path:

```
C:\Users\scfa\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin;C:\Users\scfa\Documents\myProgramms\dev_msys2\mingw64\bin;C:\Users\scfa\Documents\myProgramms\dev_msys2\mingw32\bin;C:\Users\scfa\Documents\myProgramms\ghc-8.6.1\bin;C:\Users\scfa\Documents\myProgramms\ghc-8.6.1\mingw\bin
```

Comment: What path are you using. What bitness are all the files.

Comment: Paths in the excel to the dll is absolute; if you are referring to my path variable: I will update the question; 
The system & files are 64-bit Excel 2016 runs as a 32 Bit version

Comment: 32 bit excel can only use 32 bit dlls. If it was a COM dll you can place it in 64 bit dllhost and access it as a 64 bit COM Exe from and COM client. DLL have to match bitness but EXE don't. Your dll isn't a COM DLL though.

Comment: type `ghc /?` if it obeys windows rules it will tell you.

Comment: Thanks; i did not think about this excel "feature"

Comment: Programs load and call dll functions direct. They usually pass pointers to objects/variables. 32 bit programs can't handle 64 bit pointers.